# Dunder methods for sets and dicts

Tags: python, magic-methods

If I created sets and dictionaries in Python that behave identically, I would need to create my own implementations for the `__or__` method, but what about the other ones? For example, would I really need to implement `__ror__` and `__ior__`?

Comment: re(any expression involving an object of the types would produce an identical result to the one produced by the types built into Python): to nitpick, that might be problematic. Consider, for example, `type(x) is type({})`

Comment: This is probably nitpicking, but `__ior__` is invoked from [a statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements), not an expression.

Comment: You might want to look into [abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class). Specifically, I think you'd use [`MutableSet`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSet) and [`MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping). If you subclass them, it'll tell you which methods you need to define.

Comment: @wjandrea: Unfortunately, the `dict` union operators can't be added to `Mapping`/`MutableMapping` (because it would break code that registered classes as virtual subclasses of them; it's a major flaw in the whole concept of virtual subclasses), so that won't actually solve the problem for `dict`-like things. `Set`/`MutableSet` does provide those operators though, including default implementations if you inherit from them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only working with pairs of your own custom type, or the left-hand operand will always be your custom type and the right-hand type will be a type it knows how to work with, *and* you don't need in-place mutations, then `__or__` would be enough.

You need `__ror__` if it's possible that someone will do `a_real_set | a_custom_set`, and you need `__ior__` if you want `a_custom_set |= some_other_set` to modify `a_custom_set` in-place efficiently, rather than making a brand new copy and rebinding `a_custom_set` to the new copy.

The rules for when each is needed are found in [the Python Data Model documentation for emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) (since `|` is originally a numeric operator that has been repurposed to mean union).

Comment: Does this apply to dictionary too the exact same way? Or would a dictionary be different?

Comment: @mochiwei: It's the nature of the operator itself; it doesn't matter which type it's implemented on. `__OP__` applies for not-in-place cases where the type is on the left side, `__rOP__` when it's on the right side, `__iOP__` for the in-place case (where `__OP__` is the fallback for the `OP=` case, but obviously can't operate in-place there).